# Unpredictable result with echo command when used in a for loop

Tags: buffer, stdin, code-signing

I am trying to write a small shell script to find out the signed and unsigned jars in particular directory. While the script works fine until 4-5 jars, it starts showing unpredictable results if my directory has more jars ( currntly about 25 jars). I am not sure but a possible reason for this might be related to buffering of STDIN/STDOUT. I tried to find a resolution for this in related posts but could not get a clear answer.

Here goes my script: ( it takes JAVA_HOME as an argument ):

```
#! /bin/bash
JV_HOME=$1

for i in `ls *.jar`
do
echo "scanning $i ..."
FILE=$i
$JV_HOME/bin/jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs $FILE | grep "jar verified" ;
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "\n$FILE is code-signed\n"
else
    echo "\n$FILE is unsigned/unverified..\n"
fi
```

## done

For some of the jars, it says the jar to be unsigned, when they are actually signed when checked individually with the following command:

$JAVA_HOME/bin/jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs

What could possibly be wrong with the above script?

Thanks in advance,
Pabi